# how can I draw like this?

Tags: tikz-cd

[image]
I don't know how to draw the double arrrow,the high arrow is right the low is left**strong text**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Simple! By use of `tikz-cd` package which is dedicated to draw commutative diagrams. Search for questions tagged with `tikz-cd` and try to find a digram close to what you like to have.

Answer (score 4):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep =4em]
A \ar[r, "a", shift left] 
  \ar[d, "a", shift left]  & B \ar[l, "b", shift left]
                               \ar[d, "b", shift left]    \\                
C \ar[u, "c", shift left]
  \ar[r, "c", shift left] & D \ar[u, "d", shift left]
                              \ar[l, "d", shift left]    
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Writing of the correct contents of nodes and labels I left to you.

Comment: How to replace the "curly"arrows with filled triangle ones?

Comment: @MrI2C, tikz-cd is based on tikz package, This means that you can select any arrows defined in it. See package documentation, there is good explanation and some example how to do this. Temporary I'm not on my PC, so I'm not able to show you how.